# What does val `data` mean?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A comes from the [article](https://github.com/muratozturk5/OpenAI-Dall-E-2/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/muratozturk/openai_dall_e_2/data/model/GeneratedImage.kt).

I don't understand what the `val` data mean? In my mind,  `val data: List<Data>` is correct.

**Code A**

```
data class GeneratedImage(
    @SerializedName("created")
    val created: Int,
    @SerializedName("data")
    val `data`: List<Data>
)
```

Comment: Since data itself is a reserved token for Kotlin, if you want to use it as a keyword you'll require to escape it from the complier. Hence, '`' sign is used to escape that.

Comment: Thanks! But the code can be compiled when I use `val data: List<Data>`.

Comment: I think the author of that code did it without needing to by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't use any keywords that is preserved for the kotlin language it self(which contains the keywords in [this link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/keyword-reference.html))

so in order to user this keywords as variable we need to put it between two ` so we can use the preserved keyword.

Comment: `data` is a *soft* keyword in Kotlin. It's perfectly fine to use as a parameter or property name without escaping it. I suspect the author of the linked code made the mistake of assuming it is a *hard* keyword and defensively escaped it even though it was unnecessary.